# Save AWK FNR as a Bash variable to continue search from the line

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

I'm trying to get to run this on a sorted file. This returns the last line which is less than or equal to the given value comparing the first 9 characters.

This would be done multiple times and `VALUE` would be assigned on each run and I have to continue the search from the line after which my previous solution has been found. I know `FNR` gives me the current line number but was not able to save it as a BASH variable for manipulation.

My `file` looks like this:

```
093051721DABCD
093052654EEFGH
093053087TIJKL

$ VALUE=093052054;
$ cat file | awk '{if((substr($0,0,9) <= $VALUE)){print $0} else exit}' | tail -1
093051721DABCD
```

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: 093051721 is not less than or equal to 083551726.

Comment: @HaukeLaging since the OP has wrapped the awk line in single quotes, `$VALUE` is not expanded by `bash`. `awk` probably evaluates it to nothing, and the test always returns true.

Comment: @muru That's why I have changed this in my answer. The OP example code is really evil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
VALUE=083551726
awk -v CMPVALUE="$VALUE" '{linevalue=substr($0,0,9)+0; CMPVALUE=CMPVALUE+0;
  if(linevalue > CMPVALUE) exit; lineno=FNR};
  END {if (lineno>0) print lineno " " $0;
  else print "0 ";}' file
0 

VALUE=083551726555
awk -v CMPVALUE="$VALUE" '{linevalue=substr($0,0,9)+0; CMPVALUE=CMPVALUE+0;
  if(linevalue > CMPVALUE) exit; lineno=FNR};
  END {if (lineno>0) print lineno " " $0;
  else print "0 ";}' file
3 093053087TIJKL
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this `bash` version:

```
#! /bin/bash
exec 3<test.txt
COUNT=0
while read VALUE
do
    if [[ -z $LAST_VAL ]]
    then
        IN_VAL="$LAST_VAL"
    else
        LINE="$(head <&3 -1)"
        IN_VAL="$(cut -c1-9 <<<'$LINE')"
        let COUNT=$COUNT+1
    fi

    while [[ $IN_VAL < $VALUE ]]
    do
        LINE="$(head <&3 -1)"
        IN_VAL="$(cut -c1-9 <<<'$LINE')"
        let COUNT=$COUNT+1
        LAST_VAL="$IN_VAL"
        [[ -z $IN_VAL ]] && break
    done
    echo $((COUNT - 1)) $LINE
    [[ -z $IN_VAL ]] && break
done
```

`head` (and some other tools, such as `grep` with `--max-count`), unlike `awk`, leaves the stream positioned to just after the last character read, so you can continue using the same stream to search later on. The problem is when the value read doesn't match, so you need to save it for the next iteration (as I have done in `LAST_VAL`). The values of `COUNT` and `LINE` should then be last matching line number and line. This way, the whole thing can be done in one read-through of the file.